# Is it possible to sort metabox teaxtarea values?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, metabox, options

Textarea is on an options page, is it possible to sort the values within that textarea by alpha? I looked in the Codex but do not see any mention of sorting these values.

Comment: A textarea is a single value.  The only way to sort that is to parse it somehow, with Regex perhaps?

Comment: what if the value's had been run through a foreach() statement and pushed into a select metabox using a printf() statement?

Comment: Post your code please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$values = get_option( 'option_name')
// Create array from string
$values_array = explode( PHP_EOL, $values );
sort( $values_array );
// Create string from sorted array
$sorted_values = implode( PHP_EOL, $values_array );
```

Read more about the [sort function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php)

Comment: @ville6000-this is exactly what I was wondering, I started reading about sorting arrays. In my head I felt as though the values coming from the options page textarea could be stored in an array. So I started reading about sorting an array. I just tested this and found that to accomplish what I am trying to accomplish I just drop the $sorted_values line, no need to string them back together as this is a select box. So I just grabbed the $values Array and stuffed the select box with it and it works perfect.